# Прием голосовых сообщений vk python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Меня заинтересовал вопрос. Как можно выделять голосовое сообщение из текстовых через longpool и удалять их.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
```

Я проверяю его на текст, но не могу проверить на голосовое event.voice или чего-то подобного не существует. Есть какой-то способ?

Answer (score 0):

НЕ помню точно но там есть события нумерованные. Точнее Event.type и равен какому то числу.
А вообще читай документации.

Comment: В том и проблема, что не нашел. Если тыкнешь носом, буду благодарен